# PHP java bridge installation error HTTP Status 500 -

Tags: java, php, tomcat, parallels, php-java-bridge

I am trying to install php java bridge on a windows server.
The server has pre installed Parallels panel (IIS and php is installed)
I have installed latest version of tomcat and JRE however when i try to run php-java bridage I always get the following error message . what am I missing?

```
HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server


type Exception report

message php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

description The server encountered an internal error (php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not Fast CGI module installed in your server, you must install it. After that Java Bridge will run normally.